# Rewrite html2canvs accrding to the new syntax in help docs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html2canvas

I've just downloaded html2canvs 0.5. The given syntax seems a bit different to 0.4

I'd prefer to follow the new syntax. I was using `onrendered` as I had to set height, width, transparency, etc...

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('elem'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
       document.getElementById('holder').appendChild(canvas);
    },
    width: widthVar,
    height: heightVar,
    background: undefined,
    letterRendering: true,
    useCORS: true
});
```

My question is how do I do the same (set height, width, transparency, etc...) using the new syntax?

New syntax as per the help docs:

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#elem"), {
      canvas: canVar
    }).then(function(canvas) {
       console.log('Drew on the existing canvas');
    });
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new syntax you're referring to is just the return of a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which allows asynchronous execution of the code and doesn't need event listener (i.e `onrendered`).

So *the only* * thing that has changed is this callback, that you should now wrap in the `then()`method.
The other options should still be the same, and the syntax is still an object containing those options as keys :

```js
html2canvas(document.getElementById('elem'), {
    width: widthVar,
    height: heightVar,
    background: undefined,
    letterRendering: true,
    useCORS: true
}).then(function(canvas){
  document.getElementById('holder').appendChild(canvas);
 })
```

[▶︎ fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f4fLvhea/)

<sub>* some other things may have changed but in your particular case, it seems irrelevant</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I cant find the help docs you refer to but have you tried this?

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#elem"), {
      canvas: canVar,
      width: widthVar,
      height: heightVar,
      background: undefined,
      letterRendering: true,
      useCORS: true
    }).then(function(canvas) {
       console.log('Drew on the existing canvas');
    });
}, false);
```